# Why can I assign unknown properties to literal object in typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, typescript

```
  type ExpectedType = Array<{ name: number, gender?: string }>

  function go1(p: ExpectedType) {

  }  

  function f() {
    const a = [{name: 1, age: 2}]
    go1(a)                   // doesn't complain
    go1([{name: 1, age: 2}]) // complain 'Object literal may only specify known...'
    go1(['no matter'].map(n => ({name: 1, age: 2}))) // doesn't complain
  }
```

The typescript code is as above, my question is that isn't the last three lines the same? Why the first line can pass and the second line get a complaint, and the third line get a pass?

Also on the typescript playground:
[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=4.0.0-beta&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=8&pc=7#code/AQFwngDgpsCiAe0DGIoBMAqkYF5gEEAnQgQzAB4BvYAOxIFsoAuWgV3oCMpCAaYAcyg003APwsAziEIBLGv2ABfAHwAoVcGAAzVjRQyA9jQEGAjAAoILBMlSZsASmCV1mxZtfbd+o9vNOXTU0kIylgEmA8AG1KOkYWUz4SQRYAJkUAXQ0g-jNzEicgouKSgHpS4DQDKAkaAHIQYBD6CAAbEjlszVyLGLjmYETwlOB0jKdypoMW9rlgOoB5DgArKBRgVplUUlbgejJgI1awYAlkGS0TgGsaAwB3GgA6Z7quk166272SEG26jMe+wg5mMOGUwHMsQYAyGyQG6QciOAkyqNXqjWabQ6NGyiiAA)

Comment: This is an interesting question. It looks like `const a = [{name: 1, age: 2}] as ExpectedType` will complain, but why it's necessary to cast the type, I have no idea.

Comment: What version of typescript, and where does it complain? IDE? Ng serve? ng build? somewhere else?  Depending on your version, `a` is getting typed as `any`, which will be allowed.

Comment: @cjd82187 I tried the latest version on TypeScript playground, result is the same
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=4.0.0-beta&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=8#code/ATAuE8AcFNgUQB4wMamgEwCpVgXmAIIBORAhuADwDewAdqQLbQBcdArgwEbREA0wAc2i10PAPysAzqCIBLWgOABfAHwAoNSABmbWqlkB7WoIMBGABSRWiFGiw4AlMCoaQSkK+A69oQ8a3mTi4gIMhG0sCkwPgA2lT0TKym-KRCrABMSgC6miECZuakTiElpWUA9OXA6AbQkrQA5KDAYQyQADak8rkg+RZxCSzAyZFpwJlZTpUtBm2d8sANAPKcAFbQqMDtsmhk7cAM5MBG7eDAkiiyWmcA1rQGAO60AHSvDblKQA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I found the answer is in TypeScript's document.

So the difference between the last 3 lines is that:
The param in the 2nd line is object literally, while the other 2 not, TypeScript treat literally params and non-literally params differently:

[Excess Property Checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks)

Answer (score 1):

When assigning var a to the parameter of go1(), it seems like assigning variable a to another para variable. In this case, because type of a is compatible with parameter variable type. But if you change the type to { name: number, **gender: string** }, you will still have type error.

When assigning a literal object as the parameter, there is no type cast in this case, so the compiler can detect this type error.

More details refer to [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html).

> The basic rule for TypeScript’s structural type system is that x is
> compatible with y if y has at least the same members as x. For
> example:

```
interface Named {
    name: string;
}

let x: Named;
// y's inferred type is { name: string; location: string; }
let y = { name: "Alice", location: "Seattle" };
x = y;
```

> To check whether y can be assigned to x, the compiler checks each
> property of x to find a corresponding compatible property in y. In
> this case, y must have a member called name that is a string. It does,
> so the assignment is allowed.

Comment: Thank you for your great explanation, I edited the question and add another last line, `go1(['no matter'].map(n => ({name: 1, age: 2})))`
from what I understanding this is also a literal situation, why this line has no complaint?

Comment: Hope this will help you.https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3755